# No such module 'GoogleAPIClientForREST'

Tags: swift, xcode, api, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to import GoogleAPIClientForREST but Xcode is unable to find the module. I installed the following pods:

pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Calendar'

GoogleSignIn is working and looks like all of the necessary files for GoogleAPIClientForREST were created in the project. In addition, I created a bridging header file with the following code:

#import "GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth.h"
#import "GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcherLogging.h"

Not sure what I am doing wrong? I know others have run into this issue and I went through all of the provided solutions to no avail. I think I may need to add drag GTLR.framework to the project's Linked Frameworks source group, but am not sure how to do that nor if I actually need to given I installed GoogleAPIClient via cocoapods. I am using Xcode 12.4 and a laptop with the M1 chip if that makes a difference.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: needed to add: #import "GTLRCalendar.h" to my bridging file and did not need to add: import GoogleAPIClientForRest at the top of my files